# Can not restart gunicorn by supervisor

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

when i run "supervisorctl status hitbot" then i face this error
**FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)**
**#/bin/gunicorn_start**
Here **BIND= ip_address:port **
 [image: gunicorn_start]

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/hitbot.conf**
[image: hitbot.conf]

But when i type these command
[image: error]

**In log file**
[image: error log]

But when it test gunicorn_start by **"bash /bin/gunicorn_start"*** then it working fine
[image: testing]

Comment: So what do you get when you run ``ls -las /bin/gunicorn_start``? The error indicates a permissions issue. Can ``botadmin`` user read and execute that script?

Comment: **4 -rwxr--r-- 1 root root 499 Mar 27 04:52 /bin/gunicorn_start** this message shown @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: So run as root ``chmod 0755 /bin/gunicorn_start``. The file isn't executable by the ``botadmin`` user.

Comment: I done that before and run this command again but same error show @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Just to confirm, what does ``ls -las /bin/gunicorn_start`` now show? Are you absolutely sure it still shows the error ``couldn't exec /bin/gunicorn_start`` and not some new error?

Comment: sorry. New error is shown in log file **Please ensure that the SHELL environment variable is set before activating shell.** @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Add the text of the new error message and the lines around it to your question, so can see context. And do not use screenshots, add it as formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: `pkill -HUP gunicorn`

Gunicorn docs: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html

"You can gracefully reload by sending HUP signal to gunicorn: `$ kill -HUP masterpid`"

or with the full command line:

`pkill -HUP -f '/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn -w 5 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 myapp:app'`